# Kivy Pyinstaller .spec mp4 type

Tags: kivy, pyinstaller, specifications

I am working on compiling my kivy app into a `.exe` and currently am working on changing the `.spec` file to include the necessary `datas`. When attaching `.kv` files they are followed by `'DATA'`. I've seen in the docs that mp3 are followed by `'sfx'`. What is the type for mp4? I haven't been able to find anything in the docs.

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-
from kivy_deps import sdl2, glew

block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(
    ['preprocessing.py'],
    pathex=[],
    binaries=[],
    datas=[],
    hiddenimports=[],
    hookspath=[],
    hooksconfig={},
    runtime_hooks=[],
    excludes=[],
    win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
    win_private_assemblies=False,
    cipher=block_cipher,
    noarchive=False,
)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data, cipher=block_cipher)

a.datas += [('Code\ScreenManager.kv', 'D:\\folder\\ScreenManager.kv', 'DATA'),
    ('Code\Main.kv', 'D:\\folder\\Main.kv', 'DATA'),
    ('Code\Begin.kv', 'D:\\folder\\Begin.kv', 'DATA'),
     ('Code\my_video.mp4', 'D:\\folder\\my_video.mp4', '?????']

...
```

Comment: I think you may be confusing some things. I have seen a similar construct where `sfx` seems to appear in the `type` location, but I think that `sfx` (in that case) is just the folder where the `mp3` file should be copied. I believe the correct `type` for `mp4` is just `DATA`.

Comment: Awww yes, that makes more sense. Would all connecting files have a type of `DATA` then?

Comment: From the [documentatio](https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/spec-files.html#adding-binary-files): `Binary files refers to DLLs, dynamic libraries, shared object-files, and such, which PyInstaller is going to search for further binary dependencies. ` So I would think tht anything else should be `DATA`.

Comment: okay I appreciate the information!